# Is there a well defined schema for semantically marking up Q&A platforms?

Tags: semantic-markup, facebook-opengraph, microdata

I am looking for a schema in microdata/open graph protocol with which I can markup content generated in Q&A platforms. Q&A platforms are user generated Q&A system like popular stackoverflow, quora, answers.yahoo.com, answers.com etc. Typically, they have attributes like  question, best answer, votes, number of answers, category, author who gave the best answer.

Comment: It’s possible with Schema.org. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22029949/1591669) to a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing specific, but a combination of schemas could offer similar semantics:

- [Product Schema](http://schema.org/Product)
- [Review Schema](http://schema.org/Review)
- [User Comments Schema](http://schema.org/UserComments)