# Why is SO using schema.org Article instead of AskAction?

Tags: schema.org

Actually I do a research on schema.org implementation for a web portal that has something like questions and answers. But now I see that stackoverflow is using

`http://schema.org/Article` for questions

instead of

`http://schema.org/AskAction` and `http://schema.org/ReplyAction`.

I think ask and reply is a much better format for a Q&A platform than an article.

Or is there a SEO reason why we should avoid `AskAction` and `ReplyAction`?

**Edit:**

Or are `AskAction` and `ReplyAction` just for communication in JSON format and not for any HTML context like Stackoverflow?

Comment: Why do I get a down vote and close flag, but not a simple line of comment? *******

Comment: One reason could be that ReplyAction ist bugged, because in their example they work with the item-property `answer` but this does not work in google schema.org validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think Schema.org’s [Actions](http://schema.org/Action) would be suitable as *alternative*. While [`AskAction`](http://schema.org/AskAction) and [`ReplyAction`](http://schema.org/ReplyAction) are certainly involved, they are not the end result.

So the question (which is currently an [`Article`](http://schema.org/Article)) *could* be the [`result`](http://schema.org/result) of an `AskAction`.

But then there is the question: Why bother adding the actions in the first place? They can certainly be used in the HTML on Web pages, like all Schema.org classes (so they are not for JSON-LD only), but it’s probably not very useful in such cases (resp. only useful for special use cases).

(Disclaimer: I never used Schema.org’s Actions and I’m not sure if I understand them correctly, but this answer reflects my current understanding from reading about them.)

<s>Also note that Schema.org classes for *Questions* and *Answers*, especially for such QA sites like Stack Overflow, are proposed and [currently discussed](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2014Jan/thread.html#msg107).</s>
Now there is [`Question`](http://schema.org/Question) and [`Answer`](http://schema.org/Answer).